# java.lang.NullPointerException when trying MOA stream clustering algorithm denstream.WithDBSCAN (How to properly use it?)

Tags: machine-learning, stream, cluster-analysis, dbscan, moa

I am new into using **moa** and I am having a hard time trying to decode how the clustering algorithms have to be used. The [documentation](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~abifet/MOA/API/classmoa_1_1clusterers_1_1denstream_1_1_den_stream.html) lacks of sample code for common usages, and the [implementation](https://github.com/Waikato/moa/blob/master/moa/src/main/java/moa/clusterers/denstream/WithDBSCAN.java) is not well explained with comments ... have not found any tutorial either.

So, here is my code:

```java
import com.yahoo.labs.samoa.instances.DenseInstance;
import moa.cluster.Clustering;
import moa.clusterers.denstream.WithDBSCAN;

public class TestingDenstream {
    static DenseInstance randomInstance(int size) {
        DenseInstance instance = new DenseInstance(size);
        for (int idx = 0; idx < size; idx++) {
            instance.setValue(idx, Math.random());
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WithDBSCAN withDBSCAN = new WithDBSCAN();
        withDBSCAN.resetLearningImpl();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            DenseInstance d = randomInstance(2);
            withDBSCAN.trainOnInstanceImpl(d);
        }
        Clustering clusteringResult = withDBSCAN.getClusteringResult();
        Clustering microClusteringResult = withDBSCAN.getMicroClusteringResult();

        System.out.println(clusteringResult);

    }
}
```

And here is the error I get:

[image]

Any insights into how the algorithm has to be used will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code.
It is working as I mentioned in the github, you have to assign header to your instance. [See the github discussion](https://github.com/Waikato/moa/issues/191)

here is the updated code:

```java
    static DenseInstance randomInstance(int size) {
        // generates the name of the features which is called as InstanceHeader
        ArrayList<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            attributes.add(new Attribute("feature_" + i));
        }
        // create instance header with generated feature name
        InstancesHeader streamHeader = new InstancesHeader(
                new Instances("Mustafa Çelik Instance",attributes, size));

        // generates random data
        double[] data = new double[2];
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            data[i] = random.nextDouble();
        }

        // creates an instance and assigns the data
        DenseInstance inst = new DenseInstance(1.0, data);

        // assigns the instanceHeader(feature name)
        inst.setDataset(streamHeader);

        return inst;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WithDBSCAN withDBSCAN = new WithDBSCAN();
        withDBSCAN.resetLearningImpl();
        withDBSCAN.initialDBScan();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
            DenseInstance d = randomInstance(5);

            withDBSCAN.trainOnInstanceImpl(d);
        }
        Clustering clusteringResult = withDBSCAN.getClusteringResult();
        Clustering microClusteringResult = withDBSCAN.getMicroClusteringResult();

        System.out.println(clusteringResult);
    }
```

here is the screenshot of debug process, as you see the clustering result is generated:

[image: debug screenshot]
image link is broken, you can find it on github [github entry link](https://github.com/Waikato/moa/issues/191#issuecomment-554897110)

Comment: Well thanks! I continued the discussion [on github](https://github.com/Waikato/moa/issues/191#issuecomment-555208983)

Comment: @onofricamila why did you approve answer, then remove it?
the code is working?

Comment: I do not know what happened. Of course I approved the answer, and I did not remove the approvation (maybe I did it without realizing it, because I also use stack overflow on my mobile - I may have touched the icon while scrolling)

Comment: Any ideas about the irregularities regarding some fields, which I mentioned on github? Thanks :)